# map по id инпутов

Tags: javascript

Функция не работает. Вероятнее всего, ошибка в объявлении input. Когда вместо map использую for loop все работает, но хочется именно через map разобраться.

HTML:

```
<input id = "nameInput" type="text" pattern="[0-9]" onchange = "func();"/>
<input id = "emailInput" type="email" onchange = "func();"/>
```

JS:

```
var state = {nameInput: {value: "", errors:  null}, 
         emailInput: {value: "", errors: null}};
var inputId = Object.keys(state);
   var func = () => {
inputId.map((item, input = document.getElementById(item)) =>        
  state[item].value = input.value);
  console.log(state)
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. За использование map не по назначению надо руки отрывать. Тебе нужен результат map? Там вообще хоть какой-то осмысленный результат получается? Нет.
2. В коллбэк вторым параметром приходит индекс, что явно не undefined, а значит значение по умолчанию не вычисляется и не используется.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался! Заработало =)